# The first list item is being Deleted not the selected item

Tags: vb6

The selected item in listview is not being deleted but the first listitem is the one that being deleted

```
Private Sub Command2_Click()
   confirm = MsgBox("Do you want to delete the Employee Record", vbYesNo + vbCritical, "Deletion Confirmation")

   If confirm = vbYes Then
      Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
      rs.ActiveConnection = con
      rs.LockType = adLockOptimistic
      rs.Open "SELECT * FROM bmsTable"

      If Not rs.EOF Then
         With rs
            .Delete 'delete listview data
            .MoveNext
         End With

         ListView1.ListItems.Clear

         MsgBox "Record successfully deleted..", vbInformation, "Success" 'display message box
      End If

      loaddata
   End If
End Sub
```

I want to delete the seleceted item in listview & database

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing how you filled your ListView, I can only show you what I might do in this situation.  Presumably your table has a Primary Key.  I would use that as the `Key` for each ListItem.  In the following example, replace `Project_ID` with the actual name of your Primary Key:

```
Set list = ListView1.ListItems.Add(, CStr(rs!Project_ID) & "k", rs!Project_Name)
```

Having filled the ListView in this manner your code becomes:

```
Private Sub Command2_Click()
   confirm = MsgBox("Do you want to delete the Employee Record", vbYesNo + vbCritical, "Deletion Confirmation")

   If confirm = vbYes Then
      ListView1.ListItems.Remove ListView1.SelectedItem.Key

      Dim CM As ADODB.Command
      Set CM = New ADODB.Command
      Set CM.ActiveConnection = con
      CM.CommandType = adCmdText
      CM.CommandText = "DELETE FROM bmsTable WHERE Project_ID = ?"
      CM.Parameters.Append CM.CreateParameter("@Id", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, ListView1.SelectedItem.Key)
      CM.Execute , , adExecuteNoRecords

      MsgBox "Record successfully deleted..", vbInformation, "Success"
   End If
End Sub
```

You will need to modify the `WHERE` clause, specifying the correct column name for the Primary Key.

Comment: The `MsgBox` displays `Record successfully deleted..` but you could get the actual number of records affected (`Dim lngRecords As Long` and `CM.Execute lngRecords, , adExecuteNoRecords`) and display an appropriate message with `Select Case lngRecords`

Comment: @KentMaquirang What was your key? If numeric, cast it to a string AND append an alpha character. The control does not like keys that are numeric or strings with all numeric characters. Here's an example illustrating this idea: `CStr(123) & "k"`.

Comment: Set list = ListView1.ListItems.Add(,, rs!Project_Name) 
@BrianMStafford      this is my code for each listitems sir,

Comment: @KentMaquirang I updated my code above.  See if it is more clear now.

Comment: I got this error sir operation is not allowed when the object is closed

Comment: Set list = ListView1.ListItems.Add(, CStr(rs!Project_ID) & "k", rs!Project_Name) this line sir

Comment: It sounds like the Recordset is closed.

Comment: i insert rs.open but this line gives me another error "invalid key"  ListView1.ListItems.Remove ListView1.SelectedItem.Key

Comment: I don't know right off hand.  I would recommend stepping through your code line by line.

Comment: Sir what if I remove the primary key because  it's give me an error if I duplicate the data

Comment: Whatever you plug in as the `Key` must be unique.  You're using this key to identify both the ListItem and the record in your DB.

Comment: I really don't get it sir about the key

Comment: In the code sample, `Project_ID` refers to a column/field in your table that uniquely identifies a record.  It looks like your table is for employees, so perhaps there is an employee id?  Whatever column/field is unique in your table is what I'm calling the key, and the name of this key is what you will change `Project_ID` to in the code sample.

Comment: In my database I did not set a primary key in my table

Comment: I did not set my primary key coz it disabled duplicate items